# How do I check if 2 clients are accessing the same data?

Tags: php

I have a page which tells me which orders are pending to verify.
I have a verification team which accesses the page and accesses each and every order.
How do I make sure that no two clients are verifying the same order at a time.
I want to make the background of that order number change the colour on other clients so that they know that this order number is being verified by someone.

I'm thinking to log the client activity in a mysql table.
Is there a better option to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create another table, where you store following data:

- `orderID`: foreign key to Orders table of order in process of verification
- `accountID`: foreign key to table listing your verification team
- `lockedOn`: a timestamp, for when someone from verification team clicked on it

When user from verification team clicks on order, you create an entry in this table, with current timestamp. When the verification process is complete, you delete the entry.

You can check, which orders have been locked, by making a `LEFT JOIN` and you can use the timestamp, to detect, when lock should have expired. And you can create a ping-home JS script in the "verification page", which keeps updating that timestamp, while the order's page is still opened.

Comment: I was thinking about doing this, but the only problem is that if an agent opens an order and then logs out, without verifying it then the order will show opened because the verification hasn't been completed, how would I resolve this?

Comment: @RahilRanka That's where the timestamp on a lock comes in. If it passes some threshold (like 10 minutes), you can release the lock, because if someone was still looking at that order (had open the page), then the ping script would have been called.